# Watch out for amzn.to links

Tags: discussion, linking

`amzn.to` is Amazon.com's URL shortener. While it can only be used to shorten links to Amazon.com, it *can* disguise affiliate tags in those links.

Comment: Handy search for finding these: http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Aamzn.to